# How to fix "SSL_Read() sometimes not reading the complete packet in case of special characters at the beginning"

Tags: sockets, ssl, tls1.2

Issue Background :
•   Some Times the Response packet from Server is not received at the Client.
•   When we check from the SSL_read(...) , the number of bytes read is not same as the Expected packet length (many times the read byte length is 1)
•   But when we repeat Sending and Reading Response, Out of 10 times we get this issue ~4 times.

Details:
•   Server sent the below data and the behaviour of SSL_read is as below.
•   Apr  5 12:45:57 rstServertest XLOG: VNAC  [01]   82 c5 b4 2e 41 39 39 39 39 39   .E4.A99999  => SSL_read() read all data.
•   Apr  5 10:30:49 rstServertest XLOG: VNAC  [01]   60 22 00 40 00 82 c5 b4 2e 41   `".@..E4.A   =>  SSL_read() read only one byte (white space) other data is missing even after we call SSL_read() multiple times.

Please let me know the root cause of this issue, and the solution.

```
// try connect if not connected
if(mConnected != true && Connect()) {
    LOGE("connection fail");
    return PERR_NET_CONNECT;
}

timeval start;
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

int remain = *len;

do {
    LOGC("Recv loop");
    int remainTo = timeoutInMs - TimeElapsed(start, MILLISEC_SCALE);
    LOGD("remain To %d", remainTo);
    if(remainTo <= 0) // timeout
        break;

    fd_set readfds;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(mSd, &readfds);
    timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = remainTo / 1000; // milli sec to seconds
    timeout.tv_usec = (remainTo % 1000) * 1000;
    int r = select(mSd+1, &readfds, 0, 0, &timeout);

    if(r != 0 && FD_ISSET(mSd, &readfds)) { // something came
        r = SSL_read(mSslConn, buf, remain);
        char buffer[512] = {0,};
        memcpy(buffer,buf,remain);

        int sslErr = SSL_get_error(mSslConn, r);
        LOGD("sslErr=%d",sslErr);
        switch(sslErr) {
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                buf += r;
                remain -= r;
                LOGC("read %d", r);
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                LOGC("SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ/WRITE");
                usleep(1000*10); // sleep 10ms ?
                break;
            default: {
                Disconnect();
                LOGE("SSL_read %d", sslErr);
                return PERR_NET_READ;
            }
        }
    }
} while(remain > 0);

*len -= remain;
return 0;
```

I have to read full buffer data sent from Server.

Comment: Please define "special". There are no "special" characters, all are equal.

Comment: I just meant values other than numbers or Hex values... but yes all are equal for the socket to read.
The starting buffer data is as below (as per server sent buffer)
`".@..E4.A     => Not Reading
 .E4.A99999  => Reading

so in first case the SSLR_Read() is not reading any data. in the second case it is able to read the full data.